# Theme Omega 3 (D7) - multiple layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I tried to use the theme of Omega 3 on Drupal 7. I like the use of column layouts with which you can choose the size of the regions.

[image]

But I do not understand how to do, when I want to use a different layout on other pages, since the "settings" of the "appaerance", provides for the regulation of a valid layout for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Delta & Context modules to achieve it, see how http://friendlymachine.net/posts/2012/creating-page-layouts-omega-theme